# How can I create a size option in Android firebase shown on my attached image

Tags: android, firebase

I have an ecommerce app, I want when user see product details they will have option to choose S, M, L, XL etc in cloth category also I like this option will show only when my category is clothing or by any name I use, please see the image for gett full idea.

Please see how I want..... I use firebase backend and want user will get functionality like my attachment

[image: T-shirt image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linear layout in vertical orientation and a radio button with custom drawable (or even buttons and handle with code the color change).

---edit---

This code is with btn but you should use radio box. [image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="S"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="S"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, actually I am new in android development if u never mind would u like to give me full code for creating my desired things?

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new product in any category where you want the sizing option to appear, create a nested loop like below:

```
Sizing:{
'small,'
'medium',
'large'
}
```

If you receive this attribute in your object call then assign the values to your UI. If the value for this Sizing object is empty then disable the element in the UI.